# All permutations of dice with a set range and sum

Tags: python, permutation, dice

I need to find out all the permutations of 10 dice (n) that sum up to 35 (m). I am new to python and got stuck on the for loop. This is what I've got so far:

```
import itertools

dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def subsets(n,m):

     perms = itertools.permutations(dice,n)
     for i in perms:
         if sum(i) == m
         yield perms
     else:
         return

print(list(subsets(10,35)))
```

Comment: Put a colon and an indent after the `if`. Drop the `else: return`, not sure why you want that.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you don't want permutations. Permutations do not include duplicates (i.e. each dice rolls a different number). There are no permutations of 10 dice rolls.

This should instead be either `product` (if you want to count `(1,1,1,1,1,2)` and `(1,1,1,1,2,1)` differently) or `combinations_with_replacement` (if you don't). I assume the latter*.

Then, there is a syntax error here:

```
     if sum(i) == m
     yield perms
```

There should be a colon and an indented block. Also, it should probably yield the current item (`i`):

```
     if sum(i) == m:
         yield i
```

This does nothing, because the function would finish anyway:

```
 else:
     return
```

So, the fixed version of the function would be:

```
def subsets(n,m):
     perms = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(dice, n)
     for i in perms:
         if sum(i) == m:
             yield i
```

Of course, that could be simplified as:

```
def subsets(n,m):
    return (p for p in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(dice,n) if sum(p) == m)
```

---

<sup>* Note that with `product`, `subsets(10,35)` yields 4395456 results, whereas using `combinations_with_replacement` you get 141 results.</sup>

Comment: you were absolutely right about the combinations_with_replacements vs permutations. that works perfectly.

Comment: I have one more question. If I need to multiply the values in the lists within the function 'subsets', e.g.: result = (numpy.product(subsets, axis = 1), I need to first store the results in another variable, and then apply 'product' module, correct?  Is it possible to insert it all inside of the function?
@zvone

Comment: This is too slow for large n. can we optimize using formula?

Comment: @PaariVendhan There are certainly faster solutions, especially for larger values of n, but that is out of the scope of this question. I would try with a recursive function (which recurses on `n-1` until it reaches `n=1`, which has the trivial solution. Then again, for the fastest possible solution, maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/ is the best place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def subsets(n, m):
    for i in product(dice, repeat=n):
        if sum(i) == m:
            yield i
```

So, you have various issues in your code:

- The for loop is not right, it is a code block that need proper indentation and a semicolon.
- The else part of the if block is wrongly set at the for loop indentation level.
- The else statement that just return will end the execution of your function.
- You are yielding the permutation object, you should yield the instance of the for loop.
- You need `itertools.product` to get the posible combinations of N dices.

Comment: You were actually right about the `product` module. I now need to multiply items in every list within `subsets` and then find their mean, however, the output is so large it causes console to freeze. Is there a way to, say, return `combinations_with_replacement` multiplied by a number of permutations for each list, so that they sum up to the `product` output? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dalvenjia has the right ideas except for the itertools function to use. If you want to roll `n` dice, you need to use `itertools.product(dice, repeat=n)`.

Comment: He needs to know how many possible combinations of all the sides in N number of dice add up to M. That's what I understood, not rolling the dice.

Comment: @Dalvenjia that's the same thing. If you `print(list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10)))` you get `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need all the permutations when a certain number of dices are rolled to get a particular total.

```
from itertools import product
dices, total = 10, 35
print([p for p in product(list(range(1,7)), repeat = dices) if sum(p)==total])
```